# Can't load Expo Vector Icons in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, expo

I have tried a **lot** of different ways to do this, with absolutely zero luck, over multiple days.

I am trying to use Solito Nativebase Universal Typescript repo to do this:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript

I have read, and tried everything on this page at least a dozen times:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/issues/43

My current `next.config.js` file looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const { withNativebase } = require('@native-base/next-adapter')
const withImages = require('next-images')
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')

module.exports = withNativebase({
  dependencies: [
    '@expo/next-adapter',
    'next-images',
    'react-native-vector-icons',
    'react-native-vector-icons-for-web',
    'solito',
    'app',
  ],
  plugins: [
    [withFonts, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
    withImages,
    [withExpo, { projectRoot: __dirname }],
  ],
  nextConfig: {
    images: {
      disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    projectRoot: __dirname,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack5: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        '@expo/vector-icons': 'react-native-vector-icons',
      }
      config.resolve.extensions = [
        '.web.js',
        '.web.ts',
        '.web.tsx',
        ...config.resolve.extensions,
      ]
      return config
    },
  },
})
```

I have also tried using `@native-base/icons`, again, no luck.

My end use case is this:

```
export const Cart = (props: IIconStyles) => {
  return (
    <Icon
      as={FontAwesome5}
      name="shopping-cart"
      size={props.size ? props.size : 6}
      color="gray.200"
    />
  )
```

Theoretically it SHOULD show a shopping cart, but instead, this is what I see:

[image: question mark icon]

So clearly there's some font issue or other issue that is preventing it from loading in the actual SVG.

I can't figure out what this is - I've tried rewriting my _document.tsx file like this:

https://docs.nativebase.io/nb-icons

I've tried adding this to my `next.config.js`:

```
 config.module.rules.push({
   test: /\.ttf$/,
   loader: "url-loader", // or directly file-loader
   include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@native-base/icons"),
 });
```

When I try to do something like this:

```
import fontsCSS from '@native-base/icons/FontsCSS';
```

in my `_document.tsx` file, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@native-base/icons/lib/FontsCSS'
```

Despite the fact that I've got @native-base/icons installed in my package.json, as well as having it in my Babel file per the instruction link above.

How do I get vector icons to work in Next?

Note, this is **specifically** Next/Expo/React Native

Comment: Dear Steven, If I was in your place, I would eject from expo to bare ReactNative or I would use [bare config](https://github.com/EvanBacon/AWESOME-REACT-NATIVE-WEB) or [example config](https://github.com/devhubapp/devhub/)

Comment: @AmerllicA I think this should still work without ejecting. Ejecting has some benefits and a lot of downsides related to codepush. But this doesn't have a whole lot to do with it

Comment: Could you update the question to include the output of `ls --recursive node_modules/@native-base/icons`?

Comment: The provided [solution](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/issues/43#issuecomment-1101070692) worked for me. Here's a [minimal reproduction](https://github.com/diedu89/solito-universal-app-icons-test). Please check it out, and comment on why that won't work well for you.

Comment: @diedu I figured out a solution, but it's only really relevant to my specific use case. I am going to delete the question once the bounty expires and SO allows me to

Comment: No need to delete it. Add the answer explaining your use case and solution, it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about setup of `next-adapter-icons` [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/next-adapter-icons).

I got it working with following approach,

- `next.config.js`

```
const { withNativebase } = require("@native-base/next-adapter");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = withNativebase({
  dependencies: ["@native-base/icons", "react-native-web-linear-gradient"],
  nextConfig: {
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: "url-loader", // or directly file-loader
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@native-base/icons"),
      });
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
        "react-native$": "react-native-web",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "react-native-web-linear-gradient",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "react-native-vector-icons",
      };
      config.resolve.extensions = [
        ".web.js",
        ".web.ts",
        ".web.tsx",
        ...config.resolve.extensions,
      ];
      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

- `pages/_document.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { DocumentContext, DocumentInitialProps } from 'next/document';
import { default as NativebaseDocument } from '@native-base/next-adapter/document'

// Icon Font Library Imports
import MaterialIconsFont from '@native-base/icons/FontsCSS/MaterialIconsFontFaceCSS';
import EntypoFontFaceCSS from '@native-base/icons/FontsCSS/EntypoFontFaceCSS';
const fontsCSS = `${MaterialIconsFont} ${EntypoFontFaceCSS}`;

export default class Document extends NativebaseDocument {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const props = await super.getInitialProps(ctx);
    const styles = [
      <style key={'fontsCSS'} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: fontsCSS }} />,
      ...props.styles,
    ]
    return { ...props, styles: React.Children.toArray(styles) }
  }
}
```

- `pages/index.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { Box, Icon } from "native-base";
import Entypo from "@expo/vector-icons/Entypo";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Icon
        as={Entypo}
        name="user"
        color="coolGray.800"
        _dark={{
          color: "warmGray.50",
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: When trying this, I get the following error: Module not found: Can't resolve '@native-base/icons/lib/FontsCSS/MaterialIconsFontFaceCSS'

Comment: Have you followed the installation steps for next-adapter-icons?

Comment: I did try that, but it just throws a lot of errors, like this: "Syntax error: Unexpected token

  35 | export const style =
  36 |
> 37 | html, body, #__next {" when I try to make the _document.tsx like suggested (even when I ignore all typescript checks)

Comment: Update your `_document.js` with the snippet I've given.

Comment: then I get this:  error - ./pages/_document.tsx:21:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@native-base/icons/lib/FontsCSS/MaterialIconsFontFaceCSS'
  19 | import React from 'react';
  20 | import { default as NativebaseDocument } from '@native-base/next-adapter/document';
> 21 | import MaterialIconsFont from '@native-base/icons/FontsCSS/MaterialIconsFontFaceCSS';
  22 | import EntypoFontFaceCSS from '@native-base/icons/FontsCSS/EntypoFontFaceCSS';
  23 | import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
  24 | var fontsCSS = MaterialIc

Answer (score 0):

Using import like this:

```
import MaterialIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
```

in place of:

```
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
```

worked for me. I think this is because of the way babel/webpack handles imports in the template. I followed the steps [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/next-adapter-icons) to setup the icons.

Here's what that looks like on web:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nope, this isn't the solution. I'm already importing based on the named export, not the default

Comment: Weirdly enough, this didn't solve my original problem, but DID solve a problem I had yesterday.